# get a random item from a list of items with property by React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, random

i am trying to get a random item from a list.
so far i managed to put my list in an array and i'm trying to get the item i need with a function but where i need it , it's undefined!
i don't know where i am wrong!!!

i wanna see the result in this console log

```
 handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    var NewDictionary = this.Dictionary;
    console.log(Rand(NewDictionary));
  }
```

the whole code is here:

```
class Application extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     value:'option2',
     button:'submit',
   };
   this.Dictionary = {
     Salam:"Hi",
     khodafez:"Bye",
     are: "Yes",
     na: "No",
     shab: "Night",
     rooz: "Day",
   }
   this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
   this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
 }
 handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    var NewDictionary = this.Dictionary;
    console.log(Rand(NewDictionary));
  }
  handleSubmit(event) {
    this.setState({button: this.state.value});
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render(){
    return(

  <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
  <div> {this.Dictionary.Salam}  </div>
  <div className="radio">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" value={this.Dictionary.Salam}
        checked={this.state.value === this.Dictionary.Salam}
        onChange={this.handleChange} />
        {this.Dictionary.Salam}
    </label>
  </div>
  <div className="radio">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" value="option2"
        checked={this.state.value === 'option2'}
        onChange={this.handleChange} />
      Option 2
    </label>
  </div>
  <div className="radio">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" value="option3"
        checked={this.state.value === 'option3'}
        onChange={this.handleChange} />
      Option 3
    </label>
  </div>
  <div className="radio">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" value="option4"
        checked={this.state.value === 'option4'}
        onChange={this.handleChange} />
        Option 4
    </label>
  </div>
  <button onClick={this.handleSubmit} className="btn btn-default" type="submit">{this.state.button}</button>
</form>

     )
   }
}
function Rand(NewDictionary){
  let i = NewDictionary.length - 1;
  const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
  return NewDictionary[j];
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <Application />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: `this.Dictionary` is an object, not an array.

Comment: Your dictionary is an Object, not an Array. Use `Object.keys(NewDictionary)` to get an array of its keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `NewDictionary` is an object and not an array, so trying to get an item by an index won't work. Instead, use `Object.keys(NewDictionary)` to create an array of keys, and then use the random index to get a random key.

```
function Rand(NewDictionary){
  const keys = Object.keys(NewDictionary);
  let i = keys.length - 1;
  const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
  return NewDictionary[keys[j]];
}
```